# Yii2 Kartik editable widget

Tags: ajax, yii2

I have a problem with my Kartik input text editable widget. It affected on the `tema` column in my table. The problem is, on my chrome developer tool it  returns an "Internal server error" on the AJAX processing. The response header's content is : `Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8` but the connection remains `close`. Is there anything wrong with my code? Note : the initial value of the editable's label is `NOT SET` (which should be the value of "tema" column retrieved from my `$model->tema`). The model name is `Home`.

My HomeController :

```
  public function actionIndex()
  {
        $searchModel = new HomeSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $model = new Home;
        // Check if there is an Editable ajax request
        if (isset($_POST['hasEditable'])) {

           // use Yii's response format to encode output as JSON
           \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

           $temaId=Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');
           $query= Home::find()->where(['id'=> $temaId])->one();

           // read your posted model attributes
           if ($model->load($_POST)) {
               // read or convert your posted information
               $value = $query->tema;
               $value->save();
               // return JSON encoded output in the below format
               return ['output'=>$value, 'message'=>''];

               // alternatively you can return a validation error
               // return ['output'=>'', 'message'=>'Validation error'];
           }  else {
               // else if nothing to do always return an empty JSON encoded output
               return ['output'=>'', 'message'=>''];
            }

        };


   return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model'=>$model,
           ]);

    }
```

The view file

```
use kartik\editable\Editable;

<?php 

    echo Editable::widget([
       'model' => $model, 
       'attribute' => 'tema',
       'type' => 'post',
       'value'=>$model->tema,
       'header'=>'tema', 
       'size'=> 'lg',
       'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
       'editableValueOptions' => ['class' => 'text-success h3']
    ]);         
?>
```

Please help. Have spent two days on this. Thanks!

Comment: `Internal server error` is for the server side and nothing to do with the javascript request or the browser, you might have to look into the logs for the server to troubleshoot the actual problem

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam You're right. I get the "try to get property of non-object' in my log and I changed my query from `one` to `all` and loop the result. But a new problem arise, The editable input value is changing, but it won't save into the database. Is there something wrong?

Comment: when you save it what does it show in console , there must be some error it is throwing , also check the params you are posting if they are correct

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I got the response : `Call to a member function load() on null` on this line : `if ($model->load($_POST)) `. It didn't suppose to be null as I have result in my databse. How to get the value of the editable field in Kartik Editable? Formerly in my code I use ` $temaId=Yii::$app->request->post('editableKey');` but I think "editableKey" property only exist in Kartik Grid Widget, not Kartik editable text input widget. In raw PHP we can simply get the value with `get` or `post` by simply use `$_POST['inputName']; ` What is the default `input name` for Kartik's field? Thanks